# can not access String variable outside of try block

Tags: java, mongodb

My java code is

```
String d="";
BasicDBObject dateq = null;
try {
    con.selectDB("test", "logData");

    dateq = new BasicDBObject("user_name", txtu);

    DBCursor searchDate = con.coll.find(dateq);
    //System.out.println(" "+ searchDate.next().get("login_date"));

    d=(String) searchDate.next().get("login_date");
    System.out.println("ddddddddddd"+d);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("First time login");
}
System.out.println("login date" );
if (d == "") {
      BasicDBObject log = new BasicDBObject();
      log.put("user_name", txtu);
```

value of `d` is null in above code. when I declare it as

```
String d=(String) searchDate.next().get("login_date");
```

It gives correct date but not accesible outside catch.I could not validate condition `if(d=="")`. Any help

Comment: try initiating the string as `String d = null;`

Comment: First of all use `"".equals(d)` or better `d.length()==0` !

Comment: d is a string use `"".equals(d)`

Answer (score 0):

You varible d should be accessible outside the block as well. Bu there are other problems in your code. You are using wrong comparision operator for string. Use equals for string comparison instead of ==. Here is the problem in your code:

```
if (d == "")
```

change it to:

```
if ("".equals(d))
```

Another logical problem is that in your code:

```
        d=(String) searchDate.next().get("login_date");
```

your `searchDate` method may return null and hence your variable `d` will be set to null. But your d null check comparision is actually wrong:

```
if (d == "")
```

should be

```
if (d == NULL)
```

Comment: How does it help , OP said *not accesible outside catch* !

Comment: @TheNewIdiot if the variable was defined inside a catch block it will not be available outside of it. The scope of the variable is within the try/catch block.

Comment: @DevZer0 Can you show me which variable in OP's code is defined inside catch block !

Comment: @TheNewIdiot OP said they used `String d=(String) searchDate.next().get("login_date");` which is defining inside the try/catch block.

Comment: @DevZer0, OP actually declared d before the try/catch. The second line was just a typo.

Comment: @John you can't see outside the box, i am sorry then believe it. and wonder why the variable was inaccessible outside the try/catch block

Answer (score 0):

When you tried the code with `String d = "";`, was the statement `System.out.println(" "+ searchDate.next().get("login_date"));` commented out or not?

If it wasn't commented out, then you would have called `next()` twice, which would consume the first (valid) entry, possibly leaving you with `null` for the second call, when the code tried to set `d`.

Try the code block again, making sure that the `System.out ...` statement is commented out (as it is now shown) - that should work.

EDIT
As suggested by Juned, you should also change how you're checking for an *empty* string.

```
if (d == null || "".equals(d))
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `if (d == "")` with `if (d.length()==0)` or `if (d.equals(""))`

Comment: both d.length(...) and d.equals(...) will throw an exception if d is null. "".equals(d) is a safer way if checking.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have declared the variable "d" outside the try catch block, it is not possible that you cannot access the variable "d" outside the block. Can you try to print the value of the d outside the block and let us know the exact error/exception message that you get. It looks like you have assumed that the variable "d" is not accessible outside, a detailed question or exception message would help to provide you very specific solution to your query.